# Tsql Column Comparision on Sample table and update rows

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures, if-statement, sql-update

I am trying to compare two columns in table 1 and update the rows in same table 1.

Sample Table

Table1 with columns A, B ,C, D

```
A B C D
-------
X 1 X 0
X 2 X 0 
X 3 Y 0
Y 4 X 0
```

IF the columns A and C are different then I need to multiply 2 with column B value and update in D column in the same table.

Required Output

```
A B C D
-------
X 1 X 1
X 2 X 2 
X 3 Y 6
Y 4 X 8
```

Can some one help with the tsql query for this please ?

Comment: Why is the last row a desired output of 8? Both A and C are the same.

Comment: I have updated now. Column A and C are different for the last row

Comment: Are columns `A` and/or `C` nullable? if so how should nulls be treated?

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
UPDATE Table1
SET ColumnD = CASE WHEN ColumnA!=ColumnC THEN ColumnB*2 ELSE ColumnD END
```

Comment: Thanks It worked. I tried the below


UPDATE 
table1
SET D= CASE WHEN A=C THEN B
ELSE 3 *B END

Comment: Then mark any of the post as answer to resolve this thread. :)